# control not getting focus after required field validation alert

Tags: jquery

i am having two textboxes and first is mandatory,when i press tab an after leaving text box empty alert comes properly,but problem is that when i set focus to the control it doesn't work,focus goes to next control because i press tab.

this is what i have written

```
$("#amount").on("blur", function () {
    if (!$(this).val()) {
        alert("This field is required");
        $(this).focus();
    }
});
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8sgcg/29/)

the above code works fine in crome but it doesn't work in Mozilla

Comment: fiddle is working properly for me

Comment: alert is coming properly,no issue in that but i want focus on that same control,in this case focus is moving to next control

Comment: here the focus is also working properlyy

Comment: which browser u r using???

Comment: the above code works fine in crome but it doesn't work in Mozilla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$("#amount").on("blur", function () {
    if (!$(this).val()) {
        alert("This field is required");
        $(this).focus();
        setTimeout( function() { $(window).focus(); $("#amount").focus() })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly improved version from vivek's answer

```
$("#amount").on("blur", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.val()) {
        alert("This field is required");
        setTimeout(function(){$this.focus();},1);
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8sgcg/37/)